# Anyone tried using MySQL DataController to setup a Federated table with MSSQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_DataController which lead me to this: https://launchpad.net/datacontroller

It looks like a plug in to let you created federated tables in MySQL to connect to MSSQL Server, but the only example they give it with Oracle.

It would be neat if this was possible, as it would solve a few problems for me.
If anyone has any experience and can point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datacontroller plugin actually works with mssql. You simply use `mssql://` instead of oracle

Comment: Good information. unfortunately, we decided not to go with mysql for this project, but I'll keep that in mind for any future projects.